# power query - split data from one column into more rows

Tags: powerquery

I am not allowed to paste an image here, so I have copied the power query table. I need to split this column into rows.
For an example:
1st row:
Q3(71.0 µm) = 63.64 %
2nd row:
1-Q3(315.0 µm) = 0.87 %
the column is pasted below.

```
Column1
"Q3(71.0 µm) = 63.64 %
1-Q3(315.0 µm) = 0.87 %
p3(71.0 µm,105.0 µm) = 13.36 %
p3(105.0 µm,149.0 µm) = 11.74 %p3(149.0 µm,210.0 µm) = 7.14 %
p3(210.0 µm,250.0 µm) = 1.88 %
p3(250.0 µm,315.0 µm) = 1.37 %"
"Q3 (b/l=0.5) = 8.80 %Mean value SPHT3 = 0.7743
Mean value Symm3 = 0.9041
Mean value b/l3 = 0.6985"
```

Comment: Just use `split be delimiter` with (if your pasting is accurate) `cr-lf` as the delimiter, and paste into rows (not the default-columns).  In M, crlf => `#(cr)#(lf)`.  Of course, your actual data might need to be split by just `lf`. You'll need to do some experimenting.

Comment: I did it. I converted into the list and then used split text and used %. I got what I need just without the % sign. Then I converted back to table and used add format -suffix - %.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I have to be honest with you. When I posted this question I had no idea the meaning of cr or lf. I went thru your question again (today), and I got myself a decent table. 
P.S As you said lf was enough. 
Thank you very much!